# Struggling with solution to inhomogeneous wave equation / Sturm-Liouville method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, sturm-liouville

I am struggling to come up with a coherent/complete solution to an inhomogeneous wave equation PDE and was hoping someone could shed some light on a few things below in my partial solution. My actual questions are **bolded**.

1. The "original" PDE I am starting with is:

$\begin{cases}
  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} u(x,t) - 4\omega^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} u(x,t) = 0 \\    
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(1,t) = 2\pi\omega\sin(\pi t) \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(0,t) = 0
\end{cases}
$

I realize there aren't any initial conditions, only boundary conditions, which is causing me some confusion later on.

2. The above PDE is readily transformed into an inhomogeneous PDE with homogeneous boundary conditions by assuming $u(x,t)$ takes the form $u(x,t) = \psi(x,t) + g(x,t)$, where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(1,t)=2\pi\omega\sin(\pi t)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(0,t)=0$. One such $g$ is $g(x,t) = \pi\omega x^2 \sin(\pi t)$.

Substituting this into our original PDE yields a new PDE for $\psi(x,t)$:

$\begin{cases}
  \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \psi(x,t) - 4\omega^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \psi(x,t) = (-2\pi\omega - 4\pi^3\omega^3 x^2)\sin(\pi t) \\    
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi(1,t) = 0 \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \psi(0,t) = 0
\end{cases}
$

From here on I'll let $\alpha = -2\pi\omega$ and $\beta = -4\pi^3\omega^3$ to keep things clean. So the above PDE is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \psi(x,t) - 4\omega^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \psi(x,t) = (\alpha + \beta x^2)\sin(\pi t)$.

3. Now, assuming $\psi(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ (separation of variables), we get the following ODEs:

$\begin{cases}
  X'' + \lambda X, X'(0) = X'(1) = 0 \\
  4\omega^2 T'' + \lambda T = 0
\end{cases}
$

Focusing on the ODE in $X(x)$, we have a family of solutions $X_n(x) = a_n \cos(n\pi x)$ (eigenfunctions) for $n = 0, 1, ...$ with associated eigenvalues $\lambda_n = n^2 \pi^2$.

4. I think here we want to have the inner product $<X_n, X_n> = \int_0^1 a_n^2 \cos^2(n\pi x) dx = 1$, so we choose $a_n = \sqrt2$. Thus we have an orthogonal basis $\phi_n(x) = \sqrt2 \cos(n\pi x)$ for functions defined on $[0, 1]$ and we can write:

- $\psi(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \psi_n(t) \phi_n(x)$ and
- $(\alpha + \beta x^2)\sin(\pi t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(t) \phi_n(x)$, where $f_n(t) = \int_0^1 (\alpha + \beta x^2)\sin(\pi t) \phi_n(x) dx$

I found that:

- $f_0(t) = \sqrt2(\alpha + \frac{\beta}{3})\sin(\pi t)$
- $f_n(t) = \frac{4\sqrt2\beta}{n^2\pi^2}(-1)^n\sin(\pi t)$

5. Substituting the above into our PDE for $\psi(x,t)$ yields the following ODEs (by equating the $\cos(n\pi x)$ terms for each n):

- $n = 0$: $-4\omega^2 \psi_0''(t) = \sqrt2(\alpha + \frac{\beta}{3})\sin(\pi t)$
- $n \ne 0: -\lambda_n \psi_n(t) - 4\omega^2 \psi_n''(t) = \frac{4\sqrt2\beta}{n^2\pi^2}(-1)^n \sin(\pi t)$

6. Using maple to solve the above ODEs, we get:

- $\psi_0(t) = \frac{\sqrt2(3\alpha - \beta)}{12\omega^2 \pi^2} \sin(\pi t) + c_1 t + c_2$
- $\psi_n(t) = c_3 \sin(\frac{\pi t}{2\omega}) + c_4 \cos(\frac{\pi t}{2\omega}) + \frac{4\sqrt2\beta}{\pi^4}$

So... In theory now we have $\psi(x,t)$, and hence we have $u(x,t)$? I am not so sure. Firstly, because there are no initial conditions, there are arbitrary constants floating around in the solution for $\psi(x,t)$. **Is that acceptable? It feels wrong to me when comparing to the below solution from Maple.**

As well, asking Maple to solve the PDE for $\psi(x,t)$ yields

$\psi(x,t) = \frac{\sin(\pi t)(\pi\omega \sin(2\pi\omega)x^2 + \cos(2\pi\omega x))}{\sin(2\pi\omega}$,

which looks nothing like my solution and **I'm wondering if I went wrong somewhere above, as this solution is so different.**

If you read through all of that, thank you.